# Javascript : passing a function as an argument

Tags: javascript, onerror

I want to load a default image if an image fails to load. I also want to call 
getLoadComplete() once the image has loaded. How do I pass the this.getLoadComplete() function into the function called on img.onerror?

Here is the code I've got:

```
    img.onload = this.getLoadComplete();

    img.onerror = function(){
        img.src = "http://xxxx.com/image.gif";
     }

     img.src = request.url;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript pass function as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/javascript-pass-function-as-parameter)

Comment: Does `getLoadComplete` return a function or is it the actual function you would like to call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img.onload = this.getLoadComplete();
```

You're invoking `getLoadComplete()` immediately, and assigning its return value to `img.onload`. You probably want this:

```
img.onload = this.getLoadComplete;
```

That is, set `img.onload` to *the function itself*, not its return value.

You don't need to do anything special in `onerror`; the `onload` handler will *still* be set to `getLoadComplete`, and when you modify the `src` in your `onerror` handler, it will invoke `onload` after the fallback image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call the function.

```
img.onload = this.getLoadComplete();

img.onerror = function(){
    img.src = "http://www.3d-maps-minus-3d.com/img/unavailable.gif";
this.getLoadComplete();
 }
```