# JavaScript function as function parameter default value

Tags: javascript, function

What would be the standard way to define a function which has an optional argument, which itself is a function?

For example I want anotherFunction() to return true, if it's not defined.

```
function myFunction ( anotherFunction ) {
    /*
    some code here
    */
    return anotherFunction ();
}
```

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/javascript-pass-function-as-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myFunction ( anotherFunction ) {
    /*
    some code here
    */
    return (typeof anotherFunction == "function") ? anotherFunction() : true;
}
```

This has the side effect of making sure the arguement is a function and not some garbage. If you'd prefer to throw, just use `return anotherFunction ? anotherFunction() : true;`.

Comment: The "additional benefit" isn't an additional benefit. If you function expects an argument which is a function, it *should* raise an error if a non-function is passed in. It's better to detect that and fail early, than for the function to happily proceed, disguising the bug.

Comment: That's true, but it entirely depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I used typeof anotherFunction !== "undefined" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just test if a value was passed:

```
return anotherFunction ? anotherFunction() : true
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
function myFunction ( anotherFunction ) {
    anotherFunction = anotherFunction || function(){ return true; };
    /*
    some code here
    */
    return anotherFunction ();
}
```

This corresponds to the OP's desire to default the optional parameter with a function, not merely making myFunction return true.

Comment: You're defining and invoking a function needlessly every time `myFunction ` is called.

Comment: A workaround would be to define `var trueFn = function() { return true; };`, and then use `anotherFunction = anotherFunction || trueFn;`

Comment: True. It may not be the best idea to do this from a performance point of view but conceptually I think it's the most accurate approach. In the general case, the default function could be more meaningful than merely returning true.