# How to call a separate javascript function in jquery $.each(...) instead of inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple iteration using jQuery `each`

```
 $.each(data.Limit, function (index, value) {
   alert(value.LimitCategory);
 });
```

How do I change this to call an actual javascript function - which I want to maintain separately from the loop?

e.g.

```
function DoSomethingElse(index, value){
//more things here
};
```

I've tried a few ways and can't seem to get the syntax.

Comment: `$.each(data.Limit, DoSomethingElse)`

Comment: just pass the function reference(function name) as the second param

Comment: maybe read an article on mdn about JavaScript too

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/javascript-pass-function-as-parameter

Comment: @JLRishe not exactly a duplicate. However, both questions lack basic understanding of how JS callback functions work, or how JS functions behave in a first-class language like javascript where function are just variables with a type of function allowing them to be used as a function arguments and bla bla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the function as the second param of your `each` method:

```
$.each(data.Limit, DoSomethingElse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the needed method and call it.

```
 $.each(data.Limit, function (index, value) {
   someMethod(index, value);
 });

 function someMethod(i, v){
   // process
 }
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap the someMethod in a another function.

Comment: It's just another way of implementing @ianaya89

Answer (score 0):

So when you pass in an anonymous function as the second parameter of $.each you ARE ACTUALLY CALLING AN actual JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION (sorry about the caps my phone is not behaving well.) in case you wanna define the function and pass in a function name, the syntax would be as follows.

```
function myFunction (i, val) {
    //i is for index
    //use this or val for current object in array
}

$.each(array, myFunction);
```