# NodeJS Express Dependency Injection and Database Connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, dependency-injection

Coming from a non Node background, my first instinct is to define my service as such

```
// MyService.js

module.exports = new function(dbConnection)
{
    // service uses the db
}
```

Now, I want one open db connection per request, so I define in middleware:

```
res.locals.db = openDbConnection();
```

And in some consuming Express api code:

```
// api.js

var MyService = require(./services/MyService')

...

router.get('/foo/:id?', function (req, res) {
    var service = new MyService(res.locals.db);
});
```

Now, being that Node's preferred method of dependency injection is via the `require(...)` statement, it seems that I shouldn't be using the constructor of `MyService` for injection of the `db`.

So let's say I want to have

```
var db = require('db');
```

at the top of `MyService` and then use somehow like `db.current`....but how would I tie the db to the current `res.locals` object now that `db` is a module itself? What's a recommended way of handling this kind of thing in Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer: 05/02/15**

If you want to attach a DB connection to each request object, then use that connection in your service, the connection will have to be passed to `myService` some how.  The example below shows one way of doing that. If we try to use `db.current` or something to that effect, we'll be storing state in our DB module.  In my experience, that will lead to trouble.

Alternatively, I lay out the approach I've used (and still use) in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183905/best-way-to-use-oop-in-express-rest-api/28227048#28227048).  What this means for this example is the following:

```
// api.js
var MyService = require(./services/MyService')

...

router.get('/foo/:id?', function (req, res) {
    MyService.performTask(req.params.id);
});


// MyService.js
var db = require('db');
module.exports = {
   performTask: function(id)
      {
         var connection = db.getOpenConnection();
         // Do whatever you want with the connection.
      }
}
```

With this approach, we've decoupled the DB module from the api/app/router modules and only the module that actually uses it will know it exists.

**Previous Answer: 05/01/15**

What you're talking about could be done using an express middleware.  Here's what it might look like:

```
var db = require('db');

// Attach a DB connection to each request coming in
router.use(req, res, next){
   req.locals.db = db.getOpenConnection();
   next();
}

// Later on..
router.get('/foo/:id?', function (req, res) {
  // We should now have something attached to res.locals.db!
  var service = new MyService(res.locals.db);
});
```

I personally have never seen something like `new MyService` before in express applications.  That doesn't mean it can't be done, but you might consider an approach like this

```
// router.js
var MyService = require('MyService');
router.get('/foo/:id?', function (req, res) {
  MyService.foo(res.locals.db);
});

// MyService.js
module.exports.foo(connection){
  // I have a connection!
}
```

Comment: right, but now my constructor or my method in MyService requires the db as a parameter. Since we're talking about how to "approach" dependencies/requirements in node, I would expect to require('db')....and since you've never seen new MyService....what would you expect instead?

Comment: Hey Jeff, I think I understand your question better.  I've updated my answer accordingly.  Let me know if I got any closer!