# How to add a extra object to a variable argument function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

P.S.: I am not asking how to pass a function to a function! I am asking how to add a argument after passing a function.

I want to pass functionA as a variable to functionB, and add a extra object to functionA inside functionB. How can I do this?

```
function functionA() {
    console.log( arguments );
}
function functionB( fn ) {
    fn( {
        c : 'extra object',
    });
}
functionB( function() {
    functionA( {
        a : 'foo',
        b : 'bar',
    })
});
```

this is the result:

```
{ '0': { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' } }
```

but what I want is:

```
{ '0': { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'extra object' } }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter

Comment: In your example you pass a function as a parameter for `functionB` and inside this anonymous function you call `functionA`. I'm curious if you want to pass `functionA` as an argument, not an anonymous one?

Comment: @RajeshPatel  I am not asking how to pass a function to a function! I am asking how to add a argument after passing a function.

Comment: @AlexanderIvantsov I am not sure I understand, but what I am trying to do is pass functionA to functionB, and add a argument to it(functionA)

Comment: btw, I edited the question, hope helps everyone get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function functionA() {
    console.log( arguments );
}
function functionB( fn ) {
    fn({"d": "c"}); //passing the extra arguments from here
}
functionB( function() {  
    var obj ={
        a : 'foo',
        b : 'bar'
    }; 
    obj.extra = arguments; //adding the arguments to function A
    functionA( obj );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! although the result have a bit different with what I want, but yeah, good example.