# Wrong runtime with Js Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-callback

I'm having a problem with a callback that I'm trying to implement, hope you can help me.

Here is my html:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs address-pager" ng-disabled="citizensCtrl.addressIndex==citizensCtrl.citizen.addresses.length-1" ng-click="citizensCtrl.nextAddress()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
</a>
```

The function in ng-click is:

```
self.nextAddressIndexCallBack = function(){
  console.log('d');
  self.addressIndex = self.addressIndex+1;
};

self.nextAddress = function(){
  if(self.citizen.addresses[self.addressIndex].district){
    self.getAddresses(false);
    self.getZipCodes(self.nextAddressIndexCallBack());
  }
};
```

In the function getZipCodes is where I found my problem:

```
self.getZipCodes = function(callback){
  if(self.citizen.addresses[self.addressIndex].public_place.id){
    $http.get(apiUrl + "/addresses/" + self.citizen.addresses[self.addressIndex].public_place.id + "/zip_codes").then(function(response){
      console.log('a');
      self.zip_codes[self.addressIndex] = response.data;
      console.log('b');
      if(callback){
        callback;
      }
    });
  }
};
```

So, the correct runtime that I expected was console (a,b,d). But this is consoling(d,a,b).

This is the best way to implement a callback? And how I do it be synchronous and execute only when it is called on getZipCodes function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.nextAddressIndexCallBack() causes the execution to the function, and  the result of that to be passed to the calling function..

Can you try the following changes:

```
self.nextAddress = function(){
  if(self.citizen.addresses[self.addressIndex].district){
    self.getAddresses(false);
    //self.getZipCodes(self.nextAddressIndexCallBack());
    self.getZipCodes(self.nextAddressIndexCallBack);
  }
};

self.getZipCodes = function(callback){
  if(self.citizen.addresses[self.addressIndex].public_place.id){
    $http.get(apiUrl + "/addresses/" + self.citizen.addresses[self.addressIndex].public_place.id + "/zip_codes").then(function(response){
      console.log('a');
      self.zip_codes[self.addressIndex] = response.data;
      console.log('b');
      if(callback){
        //callback();
        callback();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `self.nextAddressIndexCallBack()` that you passed is executed because of the parenthesis.

Just remove the parenthesis so you can pass the callback without executing it.

```
self.getZipCodes(self.nextAddressIndexCallBack);
```

Btw, this is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter/13286241#13286241).