# How to instantiate buttons in a HTML table, whose role is to call a JS function in the scope

Tags: javascript, json, function

I'd like to pass a function as parameter in JavaScript,
that function is a reference onto a function stored globally

```
alertHello = function() {
    alert("Hello")
}
```

for instance, I'd like to create a table from JSON array, which has an actions embedded array.

So I'd like to pass each function stored in actions attribute in my JSON object like this :

```
{
   ...
   actions : [
      {func : alertHello, icon : myIcon}
   ]
}
```

So when I create the table, I add a column based on the actions attributes :

```
    for(var i = 0; i < actions.length ; i++)
    {                
        body += "<button class='ui primary icon button'  onclick="+actions[i].func+"><i class='"+actions[i].icon+" icon'></i></button>";
    }
```

But I got a "function statement requires a name" error

Comment: The way you're trying to do will only work if `actions` is globally available. If so, just ad `()` at the end of the `onclick` button and you got it.

Comment: `actions[i].func` is within a string, so it's a literal, and not evaluated as the value you seem to think it is

Comment: Yes, It will work, except that the function will be triggered once the page will be loaded

Comment: Here's a simple example that will probably help you out: > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter

Comment: You're missing a +..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a JavaScript function as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter)

Comment: Where did I miss the + ?

Comment: @MA-Maddin The question title of the OP does not really match the real question, so your linked possible duplicate does not answer the actual question.

Comment: thanks @t.niese, I edited my question with something more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured out that a 'wrapping function' was what I was looking for,
and I needed to pass the function name as String in the wrapping function this way :

```
  var actions = [ { func  : 'sayHello', icon  : 'edit' }]
```

I created a simple wrapping function (notice that this works only on client side) :

```
wrapFunc = function(func)
{
    var fn = window[func];
    fn();
}
```

And then when I've to build the table :

```
body += "... onclick=wrapFunc('"+actions[i].func+"')><i class='"+actions[i].icon+" icon'></i></button>";
```

Finally, when the page is loaded, the function will only be triggered once I'll click the specific button.

I hope this could help other folks. By the way, my question was not completely relevant.

Comment: Exactly, you can also do it this way ! I tested it and it worked flawlessly in my case

Comment: In my specific case, the wrapFunc is necessary, because I need to pass parameters to my functions, these parameters will be processed by the wrapping function.

Answer (score 0):

I see no definition for body, nor do I think `+=` will work. Additionally, the function should not be wrapped in quotes or with pluses. Try this:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
for(var i = 0; i < actions.length ; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.className = 'ui primary icon button';
    btn.onclick = actions[i].func();

    var i = document.createElement('i');
    btn.appendChild(i);
    i.className = actions[i].icon;
}
```

You may also need to add `var` to your `alertHello` definition, like this:

```
var alertHello = function() {
    alert("Hello")
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/17ex1ksr/1/

Comment: You should provide the code with the question itself. Beside that your code does not work, because  `testFunc` is `undefined`at the time you create the `funcs` object.

Comment: This will load the function once the table will be instantiated.

Comment: What are you referring to? The function is only called `onclick`

Comment: In my case, I'm building a table column based on the content of actions, so it's not an alone element in the DOM, once the table is generated, the function will be called

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(var i = 0; i < actions.length ; i++)
{                
    body += "<button class='ui primary icon button'  onclick="+actions[i].func+"()><i class="+actions[i].icon+" icon></i></button>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for it, I'm not sure it could work... But it'll probably be a problem if actions[i].func is undefined ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work since `actions` is a global array, however your quotation marks seem to be out of place. So, inside your loop, instead of

```
<... onclick="+actions[i].func+" ...>
```

do

```
<... onclick='actions[" + i + "].func()' ...>`
```

This will render:

```html
<button onclick='actions[0].func()'> ...
<button onclick='actions[1].func()'> ...
<button onclick='actions[2].func()'> ...
```

Example: [Function as OnClick Parameter](https://jsfiddle.net/stephentillman/50x6bvxr/).

Comment: No this will not work, since it'll execute each call on rendering

Comment: I updated my question, it's not really in the same context, but thanks anyway!