# javascript - is not a function error when passing a function

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving `Uncaught TypeError: success is not a function` at the following code snippet:

```
waitFor(document.getElementsByClassName('class'), validate);

function waitFor(element, success) {
    if (element == null || element.length == 0) {
        setTimeout(function() { waitFor(element); }, 100);
    } else {
        success(element);
    }
}

function validate(element) {
    //do stuff
}
```

And my question is why am I receiving this error? validate function is properly defined below. I'm passing it as parameter of waitFor function and than success is undefined inside waitFor. I was passing function as parameter in javascript per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13286241/5449709

What am I missing?

Comment: When you call `waitFor` inside your `setTimeout`, you aren't passing `success`

Comment: `setTimeout(waitFor, 100, element, success)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are calling

```
setTimeout(function() { waitFor(element); }, 100);
```

success is undefined and hence can throw an error

Comment: But after correcting it to `setTimeout(function() { waitFor(element, success); }, 100);` I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: ok it should be `setTimeout(waitFor, 100, element, success)`. Thank you guys ;)