# What would be the implementation of the function in this scenario

Tags: javascript, function

We have functions created for doing all possible different arithmetic operations on two passed numbers:

```
function add(a, b){return a + b}
function mul(a, b){return a * b}

...
```

Now what would be the implementation of wrapper function so wrapper function should do what the third argument asks it to do.

```
function wrapper(a,b,..){
 ? 
}
```

for an instance, if i call:

```
var test = wrapper(4,5,..)
```

`test` value should be based on the third argument

Comment: So, you want to call something like 4, 5, and add and get the result 9, is that correct?

Comment: `function wrapper(a,b,op) { return op(a, b) }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a JavaScript function as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter)

Comment: yes @vlaz but the condition is as a user we have control over only third argument which tells exactly to wrapper function what is it supposed to do with these two argument. and without using conditionals.

Comment: I disagree with this being a duplicate. The question is not *strictly* about passing functions - it's for controlling the behaviour via a parameter. You can implement this via a callback (as the suggested dupe) but also with a switch, lookup tables, if statements and other ways. So the dupe is too restrictive on the scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in a *function reference* as a third argument and use it to calculate the result using the first two arguments:

```js
function add(a, b){return a + b}
function mul(a, b){return a * b}

function wrapper(a, b, callback){
  return callback(a, b);
}


console.log(wrapper(4, 5, add))
console.log(wrapper(4, 5, mul))
```

Note how there are no brackets when you pass `add` or `mul` as an argument - this is because if you do `add()`, you would *execute* the function and you would pass the *result* of that function. In the case of `add()`, you would add together `undefined` and `undefined` because nothing is passed in, `wrapper(4, 5, add())` actually results in `wrapper(4, 5, NaN)`

An alternative is to use identifiers for the operations. This might be useful if you can't directly pass the function but instead pass data as an action - for example, a user clicks a button on one machine and you send the instruction to a different machine to process. Alternatively, you can save the action in a database or a cookie or any storage and re-play it at a later time. You won't pass the entire logic but just the intended action and you can look it up afterwards. Here is an example of how this can work:

```js
//mapping of action name to logic that will be executed
var actionLookupTable = {
  "addition": add,
  "multiplication": mul
}

function defaultAction() { /* a no-op */}

function add(a, b){return a + b}
function mul(a, b){return a * b}

function wrapper(a, b, actionName){
  //fetch the logic to execute for the action. 
  //If the action name is not recognised, use a default one otherwise you will get an error
  var logic = actionLookupTable[actionName] || defaultAction;
  return logic(a, b);
}


console.log(wrapper(4, 5, "addition"));
console.log(wrapper(4, 5, "multiplication"));
console.log(wrapper(4, 5, "division")); //no implementation but no error is raised
```

Comment: Thanks @vlaz. This was so simple. It's a mix of plain closure and callback. when I had been asked in interview I couldn't think of this simple approach thinking there would be some rocket science involved. anyway thanks. I totally appreciate it.

Comment: @indar I'd say these two are the most common ways to implement this - either pass a function or something to signify what to execute. You can also do more with object oriented approaches but it'd be a bit of an overkill. If you were asked this question, I'd *expect* the asker was interested in the first approach. But the second one is still valid - it allows you to decouple implementation from intention and is more flexible. As I said, you can use it to record the *intended* actions and then execute them separately - this can be used to provide an undo functionality, for example.