# How can i take in a function and a string and log the result of calling the function on each letter in the string?

Tags: javascript

how could i create a function that takes in a function and a string and logs the result of calling the function on each letter in the string

```
function logger() {
}

function parse(letter) {
  return letter.toUpperCase().concat('yo').split('').slice(1).join('');
}

logger(parse, 'hello world')
```

Essentially i want each character in the string "hello world" to be replaced with yo. My code can only be in the section below

function logger() {
}

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* evidence of trying to solve this yourself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a JavaScript function as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Just like that:

```js
function logger(fct, str) {
  console.log(fct(str))
}

function parse(letter) {
  return letter.toUpperCase().concat('yo').split('').slice(1).join('');
}

logger(parse, 'hello world')
```