# How to prevent Javascript running on page load? (tried putting the function in head section...doesnt work)

Tags: javascript

```html
   ` 

<html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>
                   <h2>you have <span id="timer"> </span> seconds left</h2>
                   <input type="button" id="next" value="First Question" >
     <script>
                  const nextbtn=document.getElementById("next");
                  nextbtn.addEventListener("click",timedis()); 
                  var timecount=60;
                  function timedis(){ 
                  setInterval(function(){
                   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=timecount;
                   timecount-=1;
                   },1000); 
           </script>    
      </body>       
    </html>
```

Comment: `timedis()` calls the function immediately. Remove the parenthesis.

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter