# Send property as argument in function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, arguments, settimeout

I have a bootstrap alert that is being called a few different times so I want write a function to reuse. I want the alert to disappear after 3 seconds and also do something. So in my setTimeout I want to do things like `location.reload()` or `textbox.value=""`.

My code:

```
const alerts = (msg, todo) => {
  alert.classList.remove("d-none");
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = msg;
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert.classList.add("d-none");
    todo;
  }, 3000);
};

alerts("message1", location.reload());
alerts("message2", (textbox.value=""));
```

My second argument is not being called. Hoe do I fix that?

Comment: Well you can pass an actual function, like `alerts("message1", () => location.reload());`. And call it in your alerts function with `todo()`.

Comment: @SergeySosunov, not sure what you mean

Comment: You are calling `alerts` function with first argument of type string and second argument is of type (anything that is returned by `location.reload()` or `(textbox.value="")`. You are not passing a functions, callbacks, you are evaluating those functions in place and passing their "return" result to your `alerts` function. And if you want to execute some `function` that is passed as a `todo` variable - pass a real `functions`, like `() => {someCodeHere}` and then call this `function` with `todo()` instead of `todo;`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a JavaScript function as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sergey suggested in the comments, you can use [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) to achieve what you are trying to do.

Anything that you provide as part of the callback will be executed when `todo()` is called in the `alerts` function.

**Example:**

```js
const alerts = (msg, todo) => {
  console.log(msg)
  setTimeout(() => {
    todo();
  }, 3000);
};

alerts("message1", () => {
  //location.reload()
  console.log("message 1 callback")
});

alerts("message2", () => {
  //textbox.value = ""
  console.log("message 2 callback")
});
```