# JavaScript closure can't access outer variables

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I have such a code and don't know why in anonymous function passed to nv.addGraph() I can't access variables from outer function like *a*, *zcls* or *this.model*.

```
function (out) {
// Here you call the "this" means the widget instance. (@see Mylable.js)
var zcls = this.getZclass(),
uuid = this.uuid;

// The this.domAttrs_() means it will prepare some dom attributes,
// like the pseudo code below
/*
 * class="${zcls} ${this.getSclass()}" id="${uuid}"
 */
var a = this.domAttrs_();
out.push('<span ', this.domAttrs_(), '>fds</span><div id="chart"><svg></svg></div>');



nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
    .transitionDuration(350)
    .reduceXTicks(true)   // If 'false', every single x-axis tick label
    // will be rendered.
    .rotateLabels(0)      // Angle to rotate x-axis labels.
    .showControls(true)   // Allow user to switch between 'Grouped' and
    // 'Stacked' mode.
    .groupSpacing(0.1)    // Distance between each group of bars.
    ;

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

    var data = [{
        key: 'Some key',
        color: '#ff44ee',
        values: [{
            x: 1,
            y: 3
        }, {
            x: 3,
            y: 4
        }]
    }]

    d3.select('#chart svg').datum(data).call(chart);
//      d3.select('#chart svg').datum(this.model.data).call(chart);

    var someData = this.model.data;

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});
```

This function is in some way used in ZKoss Widget so in this function it's possible to access its properties like this.model, but it's not possible in inner anonymous function. I have no idea what's wrong with it, I just started coding in JS.

Comment: I can't see where you *try* to use `a` or `zcls` in the anonymous function, or where `this.model` gets defined in the first place.

Comment: When I wrote I can't access a zcls I meant I can't see them in chrome debugger. this.model is defined by ZKoss framework, in debugger I can see it in outer function but no in inner function.

Comment: You cannot see them in Chrome's debugger because you didn't access them, not because you can't. If you add access to them in the closure they will appear in the debugger. Chrome optimizes closures (eliding variables that are not used from the closure) so the debugger doesn't have them to show.

Comment: I received _Cannot read property 'data' of undefined_ in line `var someData = this.model.data;`

Answer (score 2):

The this keyword in JavaScript doesn't work the same as in other OO languages for example Java . It's value is determined during run-time and it depends exclusively on the way we invoke a function.

There are four different ways that a function can be called:

1. Constructor call: Using the new keyword; This refers to the newly created instance

   function Car = function(){ //... }
   var car = new Car();
2. Function call: When invoking a function that is defined in some scope e.g. global scope.In this case, this refers to the global object

   function someFunc(){}
   someFunc();
3. Method call: When invoking a function that is defined as a member of an object. e.g.

   var obj = { func: function(){} } 
   obj.func();

In this case this points to the object itself.

4  Call/Apply: Finally a function can be called with the help of two methods that are defined on the prototype of the Function constructor. In this case we are free to set the value of this ourselves;
    var obj = { func: function(){} } 
    function someFunc(){}

```
someFunc.call(obj);
```

In your case, in order to access `this.model` you need to explicitly define where you want the this keyword to point.

You have to options:

1. Define a local variable e.g. `var that = this;`
2. Use the ES5 `bind`method

   nv.addGraph(function () {
      ...
   }.bind(this));

Answer (score 1):

You don't access `a` or `zcls` in your closure but you should have no problem doing so.

As for `this`, it is always a function local reference that is set by the caller of the function. If you want access to `this` as viewed by the parent function you need to either copy it to a local variable such as,

```
var that = this;
```

in the parent and then refer to `that` instead of `this` in the closure, or, alternately, you can call `bind()` on the function passing in this such as.

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
   ...
}.bind(this));
```

which will cause the `this` in the function to be the same value as the parent's `this`.

Answer (score 0):

An inner anonymous function will have the same scope as it's containing function.

You may consider passing-in `zcls`, or defining it within the function you are passing to `nv.addGraph`

MDN explains this really well:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

You could define the function argument, then pass it by name.  For example:

`var fcnArg = function() { ... }`

`nv.addGraph(fcnArg);`

Another good discussion on this available here:
[Passing a function as an argument in a javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752030/passing-a-function-as-an-argument-in-a-javascript-function)

Comment: An inner function doesn't have the same scope as it's containing function. Each function executes in its own scope; It's the scope chain that allow inner functions to access variables that are defined in the outer scopes