# recursion in javascript: don't quite understand

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm practicing using recursion, and there's something I don't quite get.
For example, I wrote this simple countdown function, which is supposed to wait until a second elapsed until counting down to the next second.

I first wrote it like so:

```
function countdown(sec) {
  console.warn(sec);
  if(sec > 0) {
     sec--;
     setTimeout(countdown(sec), 1000);
  }
}
```

It does not wait one second between each log.
This works:

```
function countdown(sec){
   console.warn(sec);
   setTimeout(function() {
       sec--;
       if (sec > 0) {
          countdown(sec);
       }
   }, 1000);
};
```

I don't really understand what's wrong with the first approach.
I guess it's something with setTimeout that I don't quite understand, and scoping..?

Thanks in advance for any explanations.

--- edited & working, thanks guys! ---

I didn't know about bind being used as a shorthand.

```
function countdown(sec) {
   console.warn(sec);
   if (sec > 0) {
       sec--;
       setTimeout(countdown.bind(null, sec), 1000);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you are getting confused with passing a function as argument vs calling the function. The first one calls a function hence the recursion and the second one passes a function as parameter which is what is required

Comment: Google for "settimeout called immediately", there are too many results there and I cannot pick one that is the best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a function as an argument in a javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752030/passing-a-function-as-an-argument-in-a-javascript-function)

Comment: setTimeout expects first parameter as a function, In your first approach - you are executing the function. so you can modify you setTimeout call to `setTimeout(countdown.bind(this, sec), 1000);`. Here `bind` will return a closure i.e) a scoped function which holds your `sec` value

Comment: oh thank you ajai & smac89! understood. 

yes indeed, in the first approach, I'm calling countdown(sec)
so, this works, even without the bind:
`setTimeout(function(){countdown(sec)}, 1000)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first argument to `setTimeout` should be a function.

When you call `setTimeout(countdown(sec),1000)`, it gets evaluated to `setTimeout(undefined, 1000)` because `countdown(sec)` does not return a value.

Your second method works, but as shorthand you could also do this: `setTimout(coundown.bind(null, sec), 1000)`. This creates a function that will execute `countdown(sec)` when called, which is basically equivalent to the following:

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        countdown(sec);
    }, 
    1000
);
```

More info here:
[Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Answer (score 1):

JosephNields is correct for *why* your code was not working, but I'd also like to stress that recursion generally doesn't involve mutating state values, ie `sec--`

Instead, just pass `sec - 1` as the next value for `countdown`. In other words, there's no gain in *setting* `sec` to a smaller number, just recurse with the smaller number

```js
var countdown = function (sec) {
  console.log(sec)
  if (sec > 0)
    setTimeout(countdown, 1000, sec - 1)
}

countdown(10)
```

Also, wouldn't it be great to know when a timer is done? This example shows passing around another value as you recurse.

```js
var countdown = function (sec, done) {
  console.log(sec)
  if (sec > 0)
    setTimeout(countdown, 1000, sec - 1, done)
  else
    done()
}

countdown(5, function () {
  console.log('timer is all done!')
})
```

Comment: to be fair sec - 1 doesn't really mutate state. Setting sec in one closure won't change its value in another. But it is cleaner to just write sec-1

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. `sec - 1` does not mutate state; that is correct. But! *"setting sec in one closure"* – assuming you're referring to `sec--` – *does* actually mutate state. It's only irrelevant in this case because Numbers are pass-by-value in a function application.

Comment: that's what I mean - it's just passing the value. So if you access `sec` somewhere after the recursive call, it will have the value originally passed to the recursive call, and not any value set by the recursive call